# Spring Thymelaf in form table list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I pass multiple object from my GET request page. And one of them is `ReplacedPartList` as a list of `ReplacedPart`.

**ReplacedPart.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "replaced_part_id")
private Long replacedPartId;

@Column(name = "maintain_id")
private Long maintainId;

@Column(name = "part_serial_no")
private String partSerialNo;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private Long quantity;

@Column(name = "unit_price")
private Double unitPrice;

@Column(name = "total_price")
private Double totalPrice;

//GETTERS and SETTERS
```

**Part of my controller's GET method**

```
List<ReplacedPart> replacedPartList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    ReplacedPart replacedPart = new ReplacedPart();
    replacedPartList.add(replacedPart);
}
model.addAttribute("replacedPartList", replacedPartList);
```

**part of my returned form**

```
<tr th:each="replacedPart, stat : ${replacedPartList}">
    <td th:text="${__${stat.index}__}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].partSerialNo}" th:field="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].partSerialNo}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].quantity}" th:field="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].quantity}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].unitPrice}" th:field="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].unitPrice}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].totalPrice}" th:field="${replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].totalPrice}"></td>
</tr>
```

**error message**

`Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'replacedPartList[0]' available as request attribute`

And iy is just GET request not even POST. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with `MaintainFormDto` class. I created as a form object and send this to view. And then I use `*` for the object binding like this.

**MaintainFormDto**

```
@Valid
private Maintain maintain;

@Valid
private Demand demand;

private List<ReplacedPart> replacedPartList;

public MaintainFormDto(Maintain maintain, Demand demand, List<ReplacedPart> replacedPartList) {
    this.maintain = maintain;
    this.demand = demand;
    this.replacedPartList = replacedPartList;
}
//GETTER and SETTERS
```

**MaintainController**

```
MaintainFormDto formDto = new MaintainFormDto(maintain, demand, replacedPartList);
model.addAttribute("form", formDto);
```

**form.html**

```
<tr th:each="replacedPart, stat : *{replacedPartList}">
    <td th:text="${__${stat.index}__}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].partSerialNo}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].partSerialNo}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].quantity}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].quantity}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].unitPrice}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].unitPrice}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].totalPrice}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${stat.index}__].totalPrice}"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are not using the correct syntax as specified in the [doc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach)

Try this :

```
    <tr th:each="replacedPart, rpStat : *{replacedPartList}">
    <td th:text="${rpStat.index}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__${rpStat.index}__].partSerialNo}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${rpStat.index}__].partSerialNo}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__${rpStat.index}__].quantity}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${rpStat.index}__].quantity}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__${rpStat.index}__].unitPrice}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${rpStat.index}__].unitPrice}"></td>
    <td><input type="text" th:value="*{replacedPartList[__*{rpStat.index}__].totalPrice}" th:field="*{replacedPartList[__${rpStat.index}__].totalPrice}"></td>
</tr>
```

When using a list whether you want to show it so you have to not use it in a form. Forms ar binded to an object with the 'th:object' attribute. So if you will fill it it has to be a part of your model Maintain class.

Here is a full [example](http://www.javaenthusiasm.com/using-thymeleaf-in-spring-projects-part-2/) on how to manipulate lists.

Comment: I cant use " * " because I have form object which i bind with `th:object="${maintain}"`. If I use * it is trying to match `maintain` model and `replacedPartList` and got error.

Comment: That because in you list binding you are not specifing that the list is related to the th:object. Look to my edit.

Comment: Still same error if I use *.  `Property or field 'replacedPartList' cannot be found on object of type 'com.decimatech.tarim.model.Maintain' - maybe not public?`

Comment: I think you should edit the question and post the whole code to see if you are missing something out there please.

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't want this. I just want a pass list to view, nothing more. And next I will POST my table's context to controller. But this time I am just trying to list to view.

Comment: Bu This is not a POST. I didnt specify with `@ModelAttiribute Maintain maintain` in GET. Why can it try to bind with `maintain`?

Comment: As i said to you the syntax provided in the answer is the right way to iterate on list to displayed in GET. But as there is not the whole code i think your are messing something. Check the full example i added to you in the answer